# java 8 groupby multiple attributes

Tags: java, java-stream

I have list of Collections elements as below. I wanted to groupBy multiple fields like productCode and then for productpurchase type.

```
class Product{
    private String productCode;
    // this is ENUM with 2 possible values "ONLINE" or "INSTORE"
    private String productPurchaseType; 
    private String productCost;
    ...
}
```

The possible output should be like

```
ROW1::ProductCode1, Count of ONLINE,Count of INSTORE,Min, Max
ROW2::ProductCode2, Count of ONLINE,Count of INSTORE, Min, Max
```

i used below piece of code, but it doesn't give the count of ONLINE and INSTORE

```
void groupByMerchantMCCCodeZIP(List<Product> productList) {
    Map<String, Map<String, List<Product>>> output = transactionDataList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Product::getProductCode,
            Collectors.groupingBy(Product::productPurchaseType)));
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Can someone who worked on java 8 groupby let me know best way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: what is min max?

Comment: If `productPurchaseType` is an ENUM, why is it a `String` and not an `enum`? And why is `productCost` a `String` and not a number?

Comment: Take a look https://dzone.com/articles/java-streams-groupingby-examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To aggregate multiple values, you should write your own `Collector`, for best performance.

Easiest way to write a [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) is to call the [`Collector.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...-) method, in combination with a result collector class. Below is an example.

First, I redefined the `Product` to have better field types:

```
class Product {
    public enum PurchaseType { ONLINE, INSTORE }

    private final String       code;
    private final PurchaseType purchaseType; 
    private final BigDecimal   cost;

    public Product(String code, PurchaseType purchaseType, String cost) {
        this.code = code;
        this.purchaseType = purchaseType;
        this.cost = new BigDecimal(cost);
    }
    public String getCode() {
        return this.code;
    }
    public PurchaseType getPurchaseType() {
        return this.purchaseType;
    }
    public BigDecimal getCost() {
        return this.cost;
    }
}
```

Then the result collector class:

```
class ProductResult {
    private int        onlineCount;
    private int        instoreCount;
    private BigDecimal minCost;
    private BigDecimal maxCost;

    public void add(Product product) {
        if (product.getPurchaseType() == Product.PurchaseType.ONLINE)
            this.onlineCount++;
        else if (product.getPurchaseType() == Product.PurchaseType.INSTORE)
            this.instoreCount++;
        if (this.minCost == null || product.getCost().compareTo(this.minCost) < 0)
            this.minCost = product.getCost();
        if (this.maxCost == null || product.getCost().compareTo(this.maxCost) > 0)
            this.maxCost = product.getCost();
    }
    public ProductResult merge(ProductResult that) {
        this.onlineCount += that.onlineCount;
        this.instoreCount += that.instoreCount;
        if (this.minCost == null || that.minCost.compareTo(this.minCost) < 0)
            this.minCost = that.minCost;
        if (this.maxCost == null || that.maxCost.compareTo(this.maxCost) > 0)
            this.maxCost = that.maxCost;
        return this;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[online: " + this.onlineCount +
              ", instore: " + this.instoreCount +
              ", min: " + this.minCost +
              ", max: " + this.maxCost + "]";
    }
    public int getOnlineCount() {
        return this.onlineCount;
    }
    public int getInstoreCount() {
        return this.instoreCount;
    }
    public BigDecimal getMinCost() {
        return this.minCost;
    }
    public BigDecimal getMaxCost() {
        return this.maxCost;
    }
}
```

*Demo*

```
List<Product> productList = Arrays.asList(
        new Product("MILK", Product.PurchaseType.ONLINE, "3.99"),
        new Product("MILK", Product.PurchaseType.ONLINE, "3.99"),
        new Product("MILK", Product.PurchaseType.INSTORE, "4.95"),
        new Product("BREAD", Product.PurchaseType.INSTORE, "7.48")
);

Map<String, ProductResult> result = productList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Product::getCode,
                    Collector.of(ProductResult::new,
                                 ProductResult::add,
                                 ProductResult::merge,
                                 Characteristics.UNORDERED)));
result.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Output*

```
BREAD=[online: 0, instore: 1, min: 7.48, max: 7.48]
MILK=[online: 2, instore: 1, min: 3.99, max: 4.95]
```

Comment: Thanks Andreas, this was helpful and gave me a good understanding to deal with complex grouping with streaming